# Why can't I get on my horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm unable to get on my horse. I can steal horses, but *my* horse won't let me on. I really don't enjoy stealing horses all the time, because then I have bounty and then they leave me when I'm done with the quest. So I was wondering if perhaps anyone else had this problem or how to fix it? =) thanks

Comment: It's a lot easyer to just steal a horse or if your is glitched steal a new one .

Answer (score 2):

Try targeting the horse in console and using

> disable
>
> enable

If that doesn't work, try

> kill
>
> resurrect
>
> disable
>
> enable

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain it's your horse? stupid question i know, prehapse your horse is glitched? Then again maybe you don't want to buy a horse if this is the case you are awarded a horse from the Dark brotherhood, it is the same horse you are awarded in Oblivian shadowmere just work up the ranks and you get a free horse and it is rather fast, it will follow you as well All you have to do is check stables if it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded a new mod related to horses, check that. Also loading a earlier save game and see if you can get on that horse. If all else fails, you could try to disable all mods and check if it lets you on, or just resort to getting another horse if it gives you that much problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go on your horse if you're in a tight space. Try to move it out of the tight space and then ride it again. This happened to me at Lakeview Manor when I purchased a horse from my steward and rode it in the stable area I couldn't until I move it out. if that doesn't work, then:

> YOU'RE DOOMED!

Answer (score 0):

I installed 2 separate modules of Horsemen Combat, which uses the vanilla pony-type "horses" for its overhaul, whilst also running Horses Revamped - I couldn't ride on my horse again and I had to re-install and then after clean-saving UNinstalling the Horsemen Combat and it worked for 1 or 2 hours, then when weird stuff happens (like being saved from hunters on Frostfall or reloading a quicksave) I cannot ride on my horse again, as if it's being affected, even though I've searched out all the mods that seem to cause the problem. I've even re-installed Skyrim a few times, worked once but I don't think the last time until I got rid of some mod or another. It turns out Relationship Dialogue Overhaul prevents you from getting on your horse or accessing its inventory, too.

Comment: I don't think the issue had to do with mods, though.